# What is the equivalent of Model.visits.$inc() (Mongoose 2.7.x) in the current (3.8.x) version?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Mongooose ODB docs from 2.7.x say the following is valid:

```
Model.findOne({ name: 'borne' }, function (err, doc){
  doc.name = 'jason borne';
  doc.visits.$inc();
  doc.save();
});
```

That was taken from [mongoosejs.com](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) (very bottom of page) for version 2.7.x. I'm learning Node.js right now and using Mongoose and the above doesn't seem to work.

I have a schema where I have a field with mongoose set to:

```
visits : Number
```

and on an object by default I set the *visits = 0;*

When I try something like:

```
Model.findOne({'email' : req.query.email}, function(error, mdl) {
    mdl.visits.$inc();
    mdl.save();
}
```

I get the following error in console:

**TypeError: Object 0 has no method '$inc'** ?

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those number extensions were causing problems and [have been removed](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/migration.html#mongoosenumber) in Mongoose 3.x.

This is better handled by an atomic `update` with the `$inc` operator anyway:

```
Model.update(
    {email: req.query.email},
    {$inc: {visits: 1}},
    function(error, numAffected) { ... }
);
```